technical vs fundamental analysis . Which is top down approach and which is bottom up approach
Continuing the discussion https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/51675/macroeconomics-and-microeconomics my second question is can we say Fundamental analysis(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_analysis) is bottom up approach and technical analysis(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis) is top down approach in trading?
IS price of a stock the macroeconomic variable and the cashflow statements
PE ratio, Quarterly results, Earning per share, price to book ratio, ROE etc ... of that very company are microeconomic variables ?
How can we reconcile the emergent nature of stock prices, which arise from complex interactions between microeconomic fundamentals (like company performance) and macroeconomic factors (such as inflation, interest rates, and global trends), with the predictability of financial markets, given the potential for market psychology, investor behavior, and external shocks to distort intrinsic value and create volatility? Any frameworks of economics can help me out ?

Are you sure that one of them is bottom up and the other is top down? Must every concept fit in either one or the other category?

@nbbo2 what do you think

Being upfront, fundamental analysis is the right analysis. Technical analysis is bull*hit.
Pardon my french.
Also microeconomics and macroeconomics are completely compatible with each other. Technical analysis is useless.

To be frank from an investment science and Geometric brownian motion or fractal pricing mechanism of equity markets point of view, technical analysis is Junk, like comparing astronomy with astrology. There is no such thing as support and resistance levels and all the rest, merely excessive data mining and over-fititting like a broken watch you are bound to be right twice a day.

Fundamental analysis is just examining the historical accounting records as for the precision of its predicted prices, once again iffy, but it does illuminate many aspects of a companies operation and performance and is not junk. Whether it is up down top or otherwise is silly. It is just a systematic evaluation and examination of the historical accounting records and investor statements.

@ConFluentsy write an answer

Micro and macro are not compatible with each other in the real world of economics only in the arcane weird 2 dimensional world of static neo-classical-neo-liberal economics, dynamic economics often called econophysics and also behavioural economics do not have unrealistic silly dogma in a two dimensional static  world of Newtown's mechanics applied to the social sciences to get academic credibility as a hard science. Nearly all of Milton Friedman's theories are political science nothing to do with empirical economics.

@ConFluentsy i agree but how come many technical analysist are so rich like 500% ROI

@phdstudent i agree but how come many technical analysist are so rich like 500% ROI

chance flip a coin true randomness has more to one side than 50/50 but the greater the trial the more expectation reaches the average which is just the drift from holding a buy and hold strategy on the index , look up the arc sine law, and probability. People like Ed Thorp and Jim Simmons have the best real fact based investment  records over 20 years , over 5 and 10 years people can be incredibly lucky not many only a tiny fraction, but over 20 years it is incredibly difficult. And no one has ever on record got 500% ROI for 20 years.

If you have made 500% bank nearly all of it and start wagering with a tiny kelly based fraction, because you will blow most of it otherwise.

@ConFluentsy . We know that reward is proportional to risk. But in options buying has limited risk but unlimited reward whereas selling has unlimited risk but limited reward. but selling options has more probability of winning(reward) than buying. explain the relation between risk reward and probability of winning ?

From the research of Schiller who proved volatility is not so much about risk as fashion and popular sentiment, I do not accept the proposition that more risk necessarily brings more reward anymore than less risk brings less reward, volatility is not a good proxy for risk it is merely the dispersion of price over time for a multitude of reasons, and the greater the volatility provides the probability not necessarily the likelihood  of greater returns.

Buying options that are in the money are expensive but it gives a mirror probability of winning of selling out of the money options; for, that is if you are selling puts and buying calls. on average.
